# Create dynamic PDF starting from jrxml template in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF with JasperReports starting from a *.jrxml* template.
The problem is that I'd like to have a sort of dynamic behaviour among the sections of PDF, that are basically subreports. More specifically I need some sections to disappear completely when null (I'm not even sure how to check if a subreport is null) and the other subreports to fill that void moving **only upward**.

Let me give you an example:
1) Situation where everything is filled
[image: All blocks populated]

2) Now the green block is not shown because it's null, and all the blocks below move upward to fill the void left by that section
[image]

I don't think I can accomplish this with DynamicJasper am I right?

I really need to start from a *.jrxml* template created and/or customized by other people.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use ***printWhenExpression*** + ***positionType***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with `JasperReports`. What i recommend is using `iReport` tool (or some other `JasperReport` visualizing tool).

Just like each report, a subreport has a `dataSource`. When it is `null/empty`, the subreport should not render. In `iReport`, utilize the scripting language available (usually `Groovy`) and do conditional rendering of the `Detail` band that is hosting your subreport.

Hope this give you enough pointers to start.